# ServiceStack creates WSDLs? I thought WSDL was for non REST

Tags: servicestack

I'm so confused here on having a RESTful API where you expose a list of Uri Templates to a consumer and then why ServiceSTack would also create a WSDL.  Isn't WSDL for non RESTful APIs?

Comment: Some people need to consume WSDLs. So why not provide it? Remember that Service Stack is *based on messages* - it can *map* "RESTful" URLs to such messages. Also, there is a whole gamut of what tends to be labeled "REST" ..

Comment: no lets not get into the debate on what defines rest.  There are fundamentals that define rest, it's not that gray.  Your urls should only have nouns, not verbs.  THAT means it's restful period.  You cannot debate that.  The argument that REST is debatable and people view it as 100 things then why the hell does REST even hold up if that's the case?  Fact is, there are certain things you do to make it a RESTful API.  it's not a grey free-for-all.

Comment: this man is the truth.  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=5WXYw4J4QOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceStack is a Web/REST, SOAP and MQ Services Framework which allows the same service to be called via any of the above endpoints.

WSDLs are for describing SOAP Services endpoints only, not REST. They include XSD definitions to provide a machine-readable description of your services contract as well as WSDL-specific definitions for SOAP Bindings. SOAP/WSDL's are sometimes preferred since you're able to generate a client proxy from the definition to provide a native/typed API. Some enterprises and tooling still prefer using SOAP/WSDL's services since they provide better validation and a greater guarantee that services conform to their Web Services contract.

Comment: but WCF has the ability to basically create a RESTful API with attributes and expose it via WSDL I think.

Comment: but if I expose a WSDL, does that mean you can't force a RESTful URL?

Comment: you still haven't answered my first comment